# installing laravel script throws Undefined index: default

Tags: php

When trying to install larvel script  it throws the following error message:

```
ErrorException in Handler.php line 205: Undefined index: default
in Handler.php line 205
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: default', '/home/mazzuca1212/public_html/zurchy.com/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php', '205', array('e' => object(NotFoundHttpException), 'status' => '404', 'settings' => array())) in Handler.php line 205
at Handler->renderHttpException(object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Handler.php line 158
at Handler->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Handler.php line 145
at Handler->render(object(Request), object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Handler.php line 47
at Handler->render(object(Request), object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Pipeline.php line 81
at Pipeline->handleException(object(Request), object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Pipeline.php line 55
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3220
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9865
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9850
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2416
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2400
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

## What did I do ?

1. Created & configured database & user within script `.env` and `mysql.php` files.
2. Recreate db tables using:

   ```
   php artisan migrate
   ```
3. Within browser, I have verified that all Laravel script requirements exists using the following URL:

   ```
   http://example.com/admin/install/check
   ```
4. The previous error when I was trying to install the script using following URL:

   ```
   http://example.com/admin/install/
   ```
5. The script on shared hosting, but have shell access to account.

I am not familiar with Laravel, but trying to install the script and so I need to know what preventing installation, or how could I investigate this problem?

Comment: We would need the code for the script to determine what is going wrong

Comment: Hello Cameron, 
Thank you so much for your kind cooperation, here are the code : 
    protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
    {
        $status = $e->getStatusCode();
                $settings = $this->controller->getSettings();
                $data = $this->controller->CommonData(false, '', $settings["default"]);
        if (view()->exists("errors.{$status}")) {
            return response()->view("errors.{$status}", $data, $status, $e->getHeaders());
        } else {
            return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
        }
    }

Comment: You can try `dd($settings["default"]);` and see what did you get.